# C# How to get cookies from GeckoWebBrowser control

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I am using the GeckoWebBrowser control for navigate an URL.
It actually should have cookies when that page is loaded.
But if I tried to get the cookie, I get a blank text even the page is loaded.

GeckoWebBrowser m_Browser = ...

// ... after navigated.
string sCookie = m_Browser.Document.Cookie.ToString();

Is there another way to get the cookies from GeckoWebBrowser?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: you can get cookies value using m_Browser.Document.Cookie after you loading the page. can you tell me which website you are navigating ? and you dont need to use Tostring() here because `m_Browser.Document.Cookie` itself returns string value..

Comment: This website: https://trading.binaryinternational.com/#Trade   .Even I loaded this site, the cookie is still blank. The version of gecko i am using is 21.0

Comment: I think in that website they are securing the cookies by calling `javascripts`, did u tried with some other websites ?

Comment: So isn't there any other way to get cookies if they are securing the cookies?

Comment: Use `Firebug` addon in your browser and try to identify how they generating the cookies in that website, then you can get some idea ... If you have login credentials , then login after check for the cookies

Answer (score 4):

This is verified to work with [GeckoFX v29.0](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0).

```
var uri = new Uri(txtURL.Text);
//often cookies are stored on domain level, so ".google.com", not "www.google.com" (leading dot is important)
string host = uri.Host.Replace("www", ""); 
var cookies = CookieManager.GetCookiesFromHost(host);
string cookiesText = "";
while (cookies.MoveNext())
{
    var c = cookies.Current;
    cookiesText += c.Name + "=" + c.Value + ";";
}
```

Also Browser.Document.Cookie seems to be more reliable now, but I haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: They renamed CookieContainer to CookieManager, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Sire Is there any way to select a specific cookie ? For example User_ID ?

Comment: @rgerculy No, you need to loop them as of now.

Answer (score 0):

i found a reason for this issue, because the all element of geckowebbrowser is loading then you set cookie immediately, so geckowebbrowser not enough time to  authorized. 
My solution is make a button.
onload winform you do navigate url you wan, after than you click on button, behind event button you set  authorized cookie for your url. It's working for me. :)

Comment: This is my code:
private void frm_testwebdriver_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
geckowebsite.Navigate("m.facebook.com");

}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string[] arr1 = "your cookie";
string[] arr = arr1.Split(';');
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
string cookieName = arr[i].Split('=')[0];
string cookieValue = arr[i].Split('=')[1];
geckowebsite.Document.Cookie = string.Format("{0}={1}; {2}", cookieName, cookieValue, geckowebsite.Document.Cookie);
}
geckowebsite.Navigate("m.facebook.com");
}

Comment: Please put your code *directly in your answer*, **not** as a comment under it.