# Not able to read cookies from GeckoFx web browser control

Tags: c#, cookies, geckofx

I am using "GeckoFx-29.0-0.6" for having a firefox web browser control in Windows Form application.

I like to get the web control cookies in some way or other.

Using `CookieManager.RemoveAll();` I am able to clear the cookies successfully.

I saw the following link also

[C# How to get cookies from GeckoWebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485504/c-sharp-how-to-get-cookies-from-geckowebbrowser-control)

and tried the same But I am getting the same issue which he face.

Also I feel that the actual FireFox browser cookies and Gecko cookies are different. Is my assumption correct?

I also if possible I need to access the Gecko web browser cookies from other desktop application that we develop. It that possible ?

Comment: Yes geckofx will use a different profile to the system firefox and so should use a different place to store its cookies. (iirc you can change the profile directory that geckofx uses)

Comment: @Tom Thanks. I will try changing profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CookieContainer.GetCookiesFromHost(string host) or CookieContainer.GetEnumerator() to get all.

Note than host must have the format ".domain.com" with the initial dot.